# User or User Profile model for app wide relationships

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, software-design

I recently read a tweet that suggested that if one wants to avoid headaches in the future of an app, they should have the user table have only authentication information and a user profile table for everything else. That is if you have bikes and peaches in the system they should be linked to the user that owns them via the user profile id. The tweet was not clear on what the consequences of using the user profile. Are there maintainability/scalability repercussions to not following this especially in a large web app?

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't take it as a dogma, though it isn't completely worthless. Dependency is a problem: if you have to have a lot of different data that represent particular user, you'll change underlying database oftenly. In case everything is stored in a single column, you might find yourself doing repetative monkey job of "making it work" with your types/ORM and whatsnot gonna be involved in DB <-> RUNTIME communication.

It is all about splitting complicated task into smaller less complex subtasks: auth is self-standing - one of the most important - task itself and it definitely deserves some dedicated space. However, your app might be not that big, or not that concerned with users, and thus it won't be very helpful to split data into multiple columns. You must develop a deep sense of purpose and measure when it comes down to a software design.